# This is a question about payment module integration (JSP)

Tags: jsp, popup, popupwindow

This is the first time I have been asked to link the payment module, but I am having difficulties, so I am posting a question.

[image]

The approximate implementation situation is illustrated as above.

As you can see on the homepage, the payment button is shown/hide on My Page (page A) according to the payment status (if the payment has already been completed, the payment button is not visible, and if the payment is made, it is exposed). And when you click to make a payment, a pop-up (page B) appears. This popup window was used by customizing the JSP page provided by pg company. After that, the payment window (selecting a card...) will be brought up from the pop-up, and after payment is completed, the pop-up will change (Page B → Page C) to show whether payment has been completed or failed.

This is the outline situation and what I want to do is to complete the payment so that payment cannot be made again on My Page (Page A) after payment is completed. That is, I have three.

1. After payment is completed, DB is updated in the pop-up window (page C) (change payment status for the program).
2. Refresh the parent window so that the Make Payment button is invisible (the page that opened page C is considered the parent because the page opened is page A)
3. Afterwards, close the pop-up window (C page).

I wanted to do this.

In the case of the pop-up window, all of the JSP provided by pg company was used, so I tried to modify the code in the page (C page) and process it. It works as expected in Explorer, but it does not work in Chrome. The schematic code (page C) is shown below.

```java
if( "0000".equals( response ) ) {
  // When there is no communication problem
  // Successful DB processing of the result of the final payment request
  out.println("Successful final payment request, please update DB.<br>");

////////////
%>
  <form method="post" name="payAfterProcess" id="payAfterProcess" action="/mypage/Update.do">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="${requestScope.data }"/>
  </form>
  <script>
    var payAfterProcess = document.payAfterProcess;
    payAfterProcess.submit();

    if(window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
      window.opener.location.reload();
    }

    // window.close();  // chrome not working
    window.open('', '_self').close();
  </script>
<%
```

As you can see, it is a JSP, but all of it is written inside the scriptlet, so it was handled by inserting a script in between. I didn't think there was a need to do it asynchronously, so I did it like that (which is curious), but it works well in IE, but not in Chrome. I looked into which part was the problem, but the phenomenon (Chrome) was not well understood.

1. If you comment out the code that refreshes the pop-up window, the DB Update is properly performed.

   - // window.open('','_self').close();
2. If there is a code that refreshes the pop-up window, DB Update is not performed.
3. The code that refreshes the parent window does not always work.

   - window.opener.location.reload();

I didn't understand well, so I tried to process the callback with ajax because the problem is that the window is closed before the submit is processed. However using ajax, the script does not work afterwards(the DB is updated).

```js
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // console.log("readyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
  // console.log("status: " + xmlhttp.status);
  // alert("alert for console");
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 0) {  // Implementation unit upon successful communication
    console.log("1111");
    alert("1111");
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.open('', '_self').close();
    console.log("2222");
    alert("2222");
  }
}
```

I did the processing after ajax as above. Both 1111 and 2222 are displayed on the console, but the script that reloads the parent window still does not work. I am wondering what the problem is. Any small advice would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading the long article.